# Converting a partition to EFI boot, at a particular location on disc, from scratch

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I have a drive that developed a boot failure after a crash, with the BSOD error code 0xc0000098.  It was one of those crashes that proved utterly resistant to every technique I know for BCD recovery (re-formatted the EFI boot partition, ran bootsect, bcdboot, bcdedit, all to no avail), but fortunately, it didn't really have anything that mattered on it.  Having already recovered what I needed, I'm just doing some playing around with it at this point.

What I'm currently trying to do is to use only Windows CLI commands to manually build a new EFI boot parition at a specific location on the disc, namely the first 100mb of the drive where a Windows installation would put it.   The other fixed constraint is that I don't lose any of the data paritions that are already there, nor the Windows recovery partition.

Currently, that space is unallocated, with no partition information of any kind.  As far as I can tell, this means that manual allocation of a new EFI parition isn't possible to do in diskpart with the usual "create partition efi" command, because that doesn't give me control over exactly where I want to make the partition.

The only way I've found to get at it is to cheat a bit and use the GUI Disk Management utiliy to make a simple volume out of that space, which I then format in diskpart.  From there, I know I need to set the partition type (i.e. to C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B), but that doesn't seem to be quite enough to make it usable for creating the BCD.

I realize this isn't a necessary thing to do, but I'm interested in it as a thought experiment and deepening of my low-level knowledge of EFI boot partitions.   More constructively, I'm teaching boot repair techniques in one of my classes right now, and I'm trying to develop an exercise where I have them make a bootable Windows drive, using only CLI commands and utilities like diskpart.   The lower the level here, the better!

Comment: I don't usually do this, but the `create part` command does have an `offset` option. Also, I'm pretty sure that diskpart will use the first unallocated space that can fit the new partition, so it'll probably do what you want without specifying an offset

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have wait until tomorrow (or Wednesday) to try this, but reading over the documentation, it sounds promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly simple process:

1. In diskpart, run `create part efi size=100`

Assuming you have 100MB of free space at the beginning of the drive, [diskpart will create the new partition there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-efi). Otherwise, it'll be created somewhere else (wherever there's room). It isn't really necessary for the EFI partition to be at the beginning of the disk, it's just neater that way.

Note that Windows really [likes having a reserved partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-msr) of at least 16MB. This does need to be before the partition Windows is installed on.

2. `format fs=fat32 quick`

Now choose a volume letter that's not yet in use, and assign it to the new partition. In this example, let's use the letter r.

3. `assign letter r`

(Alternatively, you can let diskpart choose a letter by just running `assign`, and then find which letter it with `list vol`)

Now have Windows install its boot files on the EFI partition. Assuming the partition Windows is installed on is mounted as C:

4. Run (not in diskpart): `bcdboot c:\windows /s r: /f uefi`.

And that's all there is to it! (usually)

Comment: Thanks!  It sounds like I don't need to bother with explicitly setting the type id, right?  The "EFI" option for "create partition" does that, I assume.  What else does it do (besides allocating the space for the partition)?

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any major difference between the different types of partitions except the id

Answer (score 1):

- Let [chkdsk](https://diskpart.com/windows-10/bad-sector-repair-windows-10.html) remove bad sectors from allocation.
- Delete what is left of the boot partition, if anything.
- Rebuild the boot partition from a  [Windows 10 ISO USB](https://windowsreport.com/restore-recovery-boot-partition-windows-10) or with a third-party tool such as [Macrium Reflect](https://reflect.macrium.com/help/v5/rescue_cds/fix_boot_problems.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm asking is specifically how to do this using only the CLI.  I know how to fix things using the installer USB and Macrium.